# How can i save numbere for the next times

Tags: python

```
Fna=input('Should i print')

if len(Fna)>0:
   print(Fn)
    Fn=input('What is your favourite number')
```

I want to save old value every time and when I rerun program, I want to save old number value for example first time my number is 5 and when I rerun I want to see old number 5.

Comment: You need to save that data to the disk, and then read it when your program starts. Look into `open` for that.

Comment: Save the value to a file.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Have a look on [shelve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shelve.html) or [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#module-pickle).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to store a user's favorite number and retrieve it the next time they run the program. You can achieve this by saving the number to a file. Here's a Python script that does that:

```
# Define the filename where you'll store the user's favorite number
filename = "favorite_number.txt"

# Check if the file exists
try:
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        favorite_number = file.read()
    print(f"Your favorite number is: {favorite_number}")
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("No favorite number saved yet.")

# Ask the user for their favorite number
new_favorite_number = input("What is your favorite number: ")

# Save the new favorite number to the file
with open(filename, "w") as file:
    file.write(new_favorite_number)

print("Favorite number saved.")
```

Here's how this script works:

- It checks if the file "favorite_number.txt" exists. If it does, it reads and displays the stored favorite number. If not, it informs the user that there's no favorite number saved yet.
- It then asks the user for their new favorite number.
- Finally, it saves the new favorite number to the file, overwriting the previous value if it existed.

The next time you run the program, it will display the previously saved favorite number.